# Django - deleting object, keeping parent?

Tags: python, django, multiple-inheritance

I have the following multi-table inheritance situation:

```
from django.db import Models

class Partner(models.Model):
    # this model contains common data for companies and persons
    code = models.CharField()
    name = models.CharField()

class Person(Partner):
    # some person-specific data
    ssn = models.CharField()

class Company(Partner):
    # some company-specific data
    tax_no = models.CharField()
```

How can I convert a **Company** instance to a **Person** one, and vice-versa?
Let's say someone mistakenly created a Company instance with person's details:

```
company = Company(name="John Smith", tax_no="<some-ssn-#>")
```

I want to convert all wrong **Company** objects (that were meant to be Persons) to **Person** objects, keeping all related records (I have models with FKs to the **Partner** model, so it's important to keep the same **partner_ptr** value). I can do something like this:

```
person = Person(name=company.name, ssn=company.tax_no, partner_ptr=company.partner_ptr)
```

So far so good, but is it possible to delete the **Company** objects that are not needed anymore? Deleting the **Company** object will also delete it's parent **Partner** object (and any related to the partner, including the newly created **Person** object).

Any recommendations? Thanks!

P.S.: This is an already deployed system, with lots of data in it and it is not possible to redesign the whole Partner-Person-Company inheritance concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to go about this would be to first add a dummy `Partner` per each company awaiting deletion. After that you can update the `partner_ptr` of all unwanted `Company` instances to the appropriate dummy partner instance. Finally you can delete all the companies.

Of course you can use [South](http://south.aerocode.org) to help do this.

**Update**

Did some rudimentary testing and this works. I am using Django 1.2.1.

> I have tried this, it's not possible: In [1](http://south.aerocode.org): Company.objects.get(pk=7924) Out[1](http://south.aerocode.org):  In [2]: c.partner_ptr = Partner() In [3]: c.pk In [4]: c.delete() AssertionError: Company object can't be deleted because its partner_ptr_id attribute is set to None. Setting the partner_ptr instance to a dummy one changes the company's PK and it's not the Company.

You have to attach a new `Partner` and then ***save*** the company. Then you can safely delete it.

So:

```
company = Company.objects.get(pk=7924)
dummy_partner = Partner(code = "dummy", name = "dummy")
company.partner_ptr = dummy_partner
company.save()
company.delete()
```

Comment: I have tried this, it's not possible:

In [1]: Company.objects.get(pk=7924)
Out[1]: <Company: John Smith>

In [2]: c.partner_ptr = Partner()

In [3]: c.pk

In [4]: c.delete()

AssertionError: Company object can't be deleted because its partner_ptr_id attribute is set to None.

Setting the partner_ptr instance to a dummy one changes the company's PK and it's not the Company.

Comment: @Alexander: see my updated answer. You have to _save_ the company before deleting it.

Comment: Thank you, Manoj, indeed after saving the company it worked. According to the SQL log, it deletes only the from the Company table: 2010-09-14 20:43:49 EEST LOG:  statement: DELETE FROM "partners_company" WHERE "partner_ptr_id" IN (7924)
2010-09-14 20:43:49 EEST LOG:  statement: DELETE FROM "partners_partner" WHERE "id" IN (NULL)