# Django: How do you delete child class object without deleting parent class object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have the following models (I left out `def __unicode__(...)` for clarity):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)

class MinorResident(Person):
    move_in_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    move_out_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    natural_child = models.NullBooleanField()

class OtherPerson(Person):
    associate_all_homes = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I have the following view method for using a MinorResident object to create an OtherPerson object, like:

```
def MinorToAdult(request, minor):
    p = Person.objects.get(id=minor.person_ptr_id)
    o = OtherPerson(p.id)
    o.__dict__.update(p.__dict__)
    o.save()
    return True
```

This all works great, but I still have a record in the minoresident table pointing to the person record with person_ptr_id. I also have a pointer record in the otherperson table with the same person_ptr_id pointing to the same person, and displaying all of the data as it was before the switch, but with an OtherPerson object instead of MinorResident object. So, I want to delete the MinorResident object, without deleting the parent class Person object. I suppose I can do something like:

```
p = Person.objects.get(id=minor.person_ptr_id)
o = OtherPerson()
o.__dict__.update(p.__dict__)
o.save()
minor.delete()
return True
```

But I would like to not have a new record in the Person table if I can help it, since it really isn't a new person, just a person whose an adult now. Maybe I can I do something like this? Or is there a better way to handle model transmutation?

```
p = Person.objects.get(id=minor.person_ptr_id)
o = OtherPerson(p.id)
o.__dict__.update(p.__dict__)
o.save()
minor.person_ptr_id = None
minor.delete()
return True
```

I looked at [SO #3711191: django-deleting-object-keeping-parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711191/django-deleting-object-keeping-parent), but I was hoping for an improved answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**

Explicitly specify your `parent_link` fields and use an unmanaged model.

```
class MinorResident(Person):
    person = models.OneToOneField(
        Person,
        parent_link = True,
        primary_key = True,
        db_column = 'person_id'
    )
    move_in_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    move_out_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    natural_child = models.NullBooleanField()


class UnmanagedMinorResident(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(
        Person,
        primary_key = True,
        db_column = 'person_id'
    )
    move_in_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    move_out_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    natural_child = models.NullBooleanField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = MinorResident._meta.db_table
```

Now you can call `UnmanagedMinorResident.delete()` without deleting the parent row.

**Option #2**

Use a raw SQL query

```
from django.db import connection

minor = # MinorResident object
c = connection.cursor()
table = MinorResident._meta.db_table
column = MinorResident._meta.pk.column
# In this specific case it is safe to not escape.
sql = "DELETE FROM {0} WHERE {1}={2}".format(table, column, minor.pk)
c.execute(sql)
```

But you should probably change your data model and use the same table for both adults and minors. The properties you are storing in the `MinorResident` model do not belong there, they belong on the relationship between the `MinorResident` and the entity it is moving in/out from/to.

Comment: I wish I had seen this back in March of 2012. I did end up solving this in a way you describe, combining Minors and Adults as Resident objects, with of course a date of birth to determine adulthood. And yes, I switched so the move in and move out are part of the relationship, instead of the person.

Comment: As of Django 1.9, the answer is as simple as Foo.delete(keep_parents=True)

Comment: Note that delete(keep_parents=True) will annoyingly still delete from models with foreign keys to the parent model.

Comment: @MrDBA Have you found another way around this limitation besides raw SQL ?

Comment: @denvaar Simon Charette's answer below does the job (including as of Django 1.10) and is what I'm using

Comment: @MrDBA thanks for mentioning the reverse relationships cascading issue. That's definitely a bug that [I just reported](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27407).

Comment: @MrDBA parent reverse relationships are now preserved on [Django 1.10.4+](https://github.com/django/django/pull/7557/commits/31a56e30cfb3c8e1a9373e5abdd12b5b23d5d910).

Answer (score 8):

On Django 1.10.4+ you can use the `keep_parents` option:

```
minor.delete(keep_parents=True)
```

Else I suggest you use `deletion.Collector` with manual collection:

```
from django.db.models import deletion

collector = deletion.Collector(using=minor._state.db)
collector.add([minor])
collector.delete()
```

Comment: This keeps related records on the parent model intact, avoids unmanaged tables, and avoids raw sql. Yay!

Comment: This is possible even in Django 1.9

Comment: @AmrullahZunzunia the `keep_parents` option is broken in Django 1.9. See [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27407).