# Prevent Django cascading delete to superclass

Tags: python, django, django-models, cascade

I have these models.

```
# models.py
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50)

class B(A):
    a_ptr = models.OneToOneField('A', primary_key=True, editable=True, parent_link=True)
    number = models.CharField('Number', max_length=15)
```

The relationship i am trying to capture is that every B is also an A, but an A is not necessarily a B. I could use a ForeignKey instead, but i'd prefer to refer to inherited fields on B, such as B.name.

The way i intend to use these models is that A will always be instantiated first. And whenever a B is instantiated it will have to pick an existing (but not already taken) B.

This works pretty well so far, but the only issue i have is with cascading deletes. With this setup, deleting a B will delete its corresponding A (or at least that's what happens in django's admin). How might i turn this cascading off?

Im aware of the on_delete attribute, but if i set that to, say DO_NOTHING on the a_ptr field, it will have the effect of allowing B's to exist without corresponding A's rather than the other way around.

How can I do this?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711191/django-deleting-object-keeping-parent) is quite clever (switch `b.a_ptr` to point to a different instance before deleting). I don't know whether there's a less hacky way.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually pass `keep_parents=True` to the delete method on your model.

```
a = A.objects.create(name='a')
b = B.objects.create(a_ptr=a, number='1')

b.delete(keep_parents=True)
assert A.objects.filter(pk=a.pk).exists()
```

Note: the `keep_parents` parameter was added in Django 1.9. You will likely need to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3711306/386221) for older versions of Django.

Comment: Neither of these would support bulk deletes, correct?

Comment: Correct, `delete` method on QuerySets doesn't take any parameters. If you absolutely need to bulk delete, you can use `_raw_delete` - e.g. `B.objects.all()._raw_delete(B.objects.db)` - but this is not an official API and can change at any point. It also won't send any signals, and there is no protection for cascades.